# How do I add SecurityToken to webservice client call

Tags: java, web-services, apache, soap

I am using a java client to create a Soap request to my web service running using Apache CXF. I have added UserNameToken to client message but Apache CXF fails to process it in AbstractUsernameTokenAuthenticatingInterceptor class because SecurityToken is missing.

How do I add SecurityToken to SoapHeader ?

I am using Java to create SoapMessage. SoapHeader coming into webservice looks like :

```
<S:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    

xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-.0.xsd" 
SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">user</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></S:Header>
```

Comment: Information on your client libraries would be quite helpful. Or are you rolling the requests by hand?